# Find Project name from openstack VM

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

We have several servers in our infra for which we are unable to trace the Openstack Project Details.
Is there any way to fetch the associated project ID/ Name details from the VM?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question, do you mean "inside the vm, retrieve the project id" or "get the project id which the VM is running on from openstack-cli" ?

Comment: I have several servers, for which I am un aware of the projects they belong to. So, I want to know to which project do they belong.

Answer (score 1):

On my cloud:

```
$ openstack server show ab852bda-978e-4fd0-ba60-f4eebab327d3 -c project_id
+------------+----------------------------------+
| Field      | Value                            |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| project_id | dfe697576058427d96d59bf45433636d |
+------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is ab852bda-978e-4fd0-ba60-f4eebab327d3 here?

Comment: The server's ID.

Answer (score 1):

In VM,

```
ip a
```

So, learn ip of VM
(actually, you should be knowing IP, if you are able to connect it..)

Then, in openstack cli, filter according to ip addresses.. This way, you can learn which project it belongs to...